# Any method to limit the CPU usage of pycaffe compiled with openblas?

Tags: machine-learning, caffe, pycaffe

The pycaffe is compiled with openblas.

My pycaffe model occupies more than 20 CPU cores while training, any method to limit that?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting environment variable

```
OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=10
```

**before** running pycaffe to restrict openblas to only 10 threads.